# How to exclude the zeros that results from file's self comparisons and keep all the values other than that in the final array

Tags: arrays, matlab, string-comparison

i want to exclude the zeros that results from file's self comparisons and keep all the values other than that in the final array. what i am doing is using ~= for file comparison but not succeeded yet. Also tried strcmp. my code is as follows.

```
dirName= 'C:\Users\PCPC\U1';   %# folder path
files = dir( fullfile(dirName,'*.HWR') );   %# list all *.HWR files
files = {files.name};                      %'# file names

supfinal = [];
final = [];
dist = [];

for i=1:length(files)
  fname = fullfile(dirName,files{i}); 
  c = dlmread(fname, '', 0,0);
  c1=c(:,1);


      for j=1:length(files)
        fname = fullfile(dirName,files{j});    
        d = dlmread(fname, '', 0,0);
        d1=d(:,1);

           **if (j ~= i)**
               dist = dtw(c1,d1); %# SOme Calculation
               final = [final; dist];
             end
      end

        **supfinal = [supfinal; final];**
end
```

i want from my code to give me results other than self comparison in the supfinal array. what's wrong i am doing. How to correct?

Comment: What is variable `files1` in the second loop? Is it the same as `files` before?

Comment: I guess you need to empty `final` before 2nd loop.

Comment: sorry files1 is the same files variable.

Comment: when i take this line dist = dtw(c1,d1); just before the if condition and modify the last line of program (i.e. supfinal = [supfinal; final];) to supfinal = [final]; , it gives me the desired result (i.e. in case of 10*10, supfinal gives me 90 values discarding the self comparison values). Is this fine or i went wrong in the calculations?

Comment: I do not see the point to use variable `supfinal` at all. Your desired result should be already in `final`. Or did I miss something? Additionally, do you really need to compare e.g. files(1) with files(2) AND files(2) with files(1)? If not, just write your 2nd loop as `for j=i+1:length(files)`, and then you do not need the condition `if (j ~= i)`, and it will save you time as well.

Comment: Yes that works..thanks for making the things quite simpler to me.Be Blessed.